# Implementing jQuery inside a div that has content which was just loaded with jQuery's .load()

Tags: jquery, ajax, iframe, html, refresh

I have a div that is refreshed with .load() using jQuery. Once it's refresed new content appears in the div. However the new content has jQuery inside it, and it's not working, even though it does work when that content is loaded on it's own page.

The div is also on the parent window, however the jQuery code that refreshes the div is inside an iframe. The code calls to the top.document (parent window) to refresh the div that is outside the iframe.

I'll show the full code here:

This is the main page called test.php. It has just a simple iframe and below it is the div that refreshes when code tells it to in an iframe.

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body >
<iframe src="test2.php" width="400" height="400" frameborder="3"></iframe>
<div id="target">This text will be replaced.</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is test2.php which is inside the iframe, and it's just the beginning iframe page so you can conveniently press a link that will activate next page which turns on jQuery code when the page loads.

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<a href="test3.php">Click Me, if the div below reloads with the jqery content it worked!</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the page test3.php with the jQuery code that refreshes the div outside the iframe. The .load() works, however the .get() doesn't. I tried to call the jQuery with .get() and .getscript() but that did work. I also tried to wrap them in .bind() .on() .live() however if you know a way of using those in a way where yo think it will work feel free to post it.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$('#target', top.document).load("test4.php");
$('#target', top.document).get('testb.js');

</script>
</head>
<body>
Sent
</body>
</html>
```

This is test4.php, and it's the new contents that is loaded into the div after it is refreshed.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>....Polo</p>
<script type="text/javascript" src="testb.js"></script>
```

Now here is the jQuery I tried to implement inside the div, and it what is inside testb.js on the page test3.php, and test4.php. I was going to do more complicated code, but since no jQuery is working at all I decided to simplify it until the reason why jQuery isn't working can be found out.

```
var myvariable = "Marco";
$("p").prepend(myvariable);
```

Thank you so much to any help you can give!

Answer (score 1):

I would actually recommend you not do it this way.  Certainly you should not be having fragments which then load more fragments.  This way leads to madness.

I was able to get it to function, but if I had it to write over again, I'd do it differently.  It seems fragile, and is certainly hard to test.  I believe it works much better if the host document has all of the logic in it, and the fragments don't bring any with them.

I had trouble with load(), but I can't recall the exact details.  Possibly from discrepancies between the browsers?  We ended up using get() instead of load().

The big sticking point was $('#target') failing because the new Javascript isn't attached to the Document in time.  So it won't find an ID in the host document when triggered during a load() call.  I was able to work around this with setTimeout()

```
<body>
    <div id="stuff>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            setTimeout(function() {
                $('#target', top.document).get('testb.js');
            }, 1);
        </script>
        Sent
    </div>
</body>
```

the tricky bit may actually be in the way I grabbed the DIV:

```
$.get("/foo/bar", function(html) {
    var div = $('<div></div>');
    div.html(html);
    div.find('#stuff').detach().appendTo(target);
});
```

Comment: I just now tried that with Google Chrome, but it didn't work for me. Thank you for trying to help though!

Comment: Ah, I neglected a few details, which I've added.  Though it looks like I ended up using get(), I can't recall if it was because it wouldn't work or because it was easier to handle the other operations I needed to do.

Comment: Thank you for trying clarify, though I'm still not having any luck. I added the script to the body exactly as posted. I later tried to switch load with get. If you could post any extra code that was changed from my original example so I can simple copy & paste the exact code in that would be very helpful, if you still have the code. Thanks!

Comment: Like I said, what I'm doing is putting the content I want into a DIV, including the JS.  Then I'm extracting that from the get request and putting it into the host document.

Comment: Hi! Sorry for the delay in replying. I tried it out and it worked! Thank you so much! Yes it's very fragmented, but I don't see another way to do it, and it will be okay for now.

Comment: Great.  If you can't remove the fragment loading, can you flatten the design so only the host document is assembling fragments?  That at least would give you a path toward eliminating it eventually.